# String is NULL but IsNullOrEmpty function not working

Tags: android, kotlin, null

I am trying to do authentication for an app and my code is printing out a `NULL` for the user variable. However, when the app runs it is going to `Log.e("Execution","2")` instead of `Log.e("Execution","1")`. Why is this? Since the user variable is null, it should be going to section 1.

```
//Authentication:
        var auth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        var user: String = auth.currentUser.toString()
        Log.e("User", user)

        //*EXECUTION BEGIN*
        //If user is NOT logged in:
        if (user.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Log.e("Execution","1")

            //Do a fresh open (Splash -> Login -> Groups)
            var intent = Intent(this, SplashActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            Log.e("Execution","1a")
            finish() //Check to see if this stops Main Activity
            Log.e("Execution","1b")

            Handler().postDelayed({
                val intent = Intent(this, GroupsActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }, splashdelay)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_signup)

        } else { //User is logged in:
            Log.e("Execution","2")

            //If the user is starting up the app from a notif or another direct target screen,
            //load the appropriate screen.

            //Otherwise, go directly to the Groups screen
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_groups)

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call [`toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html#tostring) on a null object, it returns string "null".

So instead of using `auth.currentUser.toString()`, just use `auth.currentUser` and in your `if` condition, check `if (user != null)` which is used [to check if a user is signed in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#public-firebaseuser-getcurrentuser)

Comment: Lol does it really...? Wow, haha, I'm new to Kotlin. Thanks!

Comment: So the presumption here is NULL means "NULL" instead of a null value.